# C++ difference between %p and cout &ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, printf, cout

so I have a piece of code that needs to print the address of a number and an address of a ptr. 
This is the code:

```
int main() {
    float number1 = 1;
    float number2;

    float *fPtr;
    fPtr = &number1;
    cout << "Value of object pointed to by fPtr: " << *fPtr << endl;

    cout << "Value of number 2: " << number2 << endl;

    cout << "Address of number 1: " << &number1 << endl;
    printf("%p\n", &number1);
    cout << "Address fPtr: " << &fPtr << endl;
    printf("%p", fPtr);


    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

Value of object pointed to by fPtr: 1

Value of number 2: 0

Address of number 1: 0xbfb7e348

0xbfb7e348

Address fPtr: 0xbfb7e34c

0xbfb7e348

Why are the two addresses printed using the %p conversion specifier the same? When using the & the addresses are different which is what I would expect as number1 and fPtr are saved in different addresses.

In addition it I take away the & from the statement 'printf("%p\n", &number1);' the return value is nil. Could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, you're printing the *address* of `fPtr`:

```
cout << "Address fPtr: " << &fPtr << endl;
```

And here, you're printing the *value* of `fPtr`:

```
printf("%p", fPtr);
```

Those are not the same thing.

If you want to print the address of `fPtr` with `printf`, then you need

```
printf("%p", &fPtr);
```

If you want to print the value of `fPtr` with `std::cout`, then you need

```
cout << fPtr << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

The code seems to be missing the & before fPtr in the printf line. Try to change to this:

```
printf("%p", &fPtr);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why are the two addresses printed using the %p conversion specifier the same?

Well, you have

```
fPtr = &number1;

// ...

printf("%p\n", &number1);

// ...

printf("%p", fPtr);
```

It would be pretty surprising if the two `printf()` calls did *not* print the same thing, since the values they are asked to print are equal.

> In addition it I take away the & from the statement 'printf("%p\n", &number1);' the return value is nil. Could anyone explain why?

No, not in any general sense.  `printf()`'s behavior is undefined when the argument corresponding to a conversion specifier is not of the type appropriate for that specifier.  The `%p` specifier expects a pointer, but you pass a `double` (after the applicable default conversion).

Comment: And the last 4 bytes of the double representation of 1.0 contain all zeros, so if that value is re-interpreted as pointer, it could print null. However, that depends on many factors (i.e. undefined behavior).